# Select every Nth element in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to select, say, every fourth element in a set of elements?

Ex: I have 16 `<div>` elements... I could write something like.

```
div:nth-child(4),
div:nth-child(8),
div:nth-child(12),
div:nth-child(16)
```

is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 478, accepted):

As the name implies, `:nth-child()` allows you to construct an arithmetic expression using the `n` variable in addition to constant numbers. You can perform addition (`+`), subtraction (`-`) and [coefficient multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient) (`an` where `a` is an integer, including positive numbers, negative numbers and zero).

Here's how you would rewrite the above selector list:

```
div:nth-child(4n)
```

For an explanation on how these arithmetic expressions work, see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576324/understanding-nth-childan-b-selector-with-formula-in-css3), as well as the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).

Note that this answer assumes that all of the child elements within the same parent element are of the same element type, `div`. If you have any other elements of different types such as `h1` or `p`, you will need to use `:nth-of-type()` instead of `:nth-child()` to ensure you only count `div` elements:

```
<body>
  <h1></h1>
  <div>1</div>  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  <div>4</div>
  <h2></h2>
  <div>5</div>  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>  <div>8</div>
  <h2></h2>
  <div>9</div>  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div> <div>12</div>
  <h2></h2>
  <div>13</div> <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div> <div>16</div>
</body>
```

For everything else (classes, attributes, or any combination of these), where you're looking for the nth child that matches an arbitrary selector, you will not be able to do this with a pure CSS selector. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/css3-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-a-class-selector).

---

By the way, there's not much of a difference between 4n and 4n + 4 with regards to `:nth-child()`. If you use the `n` variable, it starts counting at 0. This is what each selector would match:

**`:nth-child(4n)`**

```
4(0) = 0
4(1) = 4
4(2) = 8
4(3) = 12
4(4) = 16
...
```

**`:nth-child(4n+4)`**

```
4(0) + 4 = 0  + 4 = 4
4(1) + 4 = 4  + 4 = 8
4(2) + 4 = 8  + 4 = 12
4(3) + 4 = 12 + 4 = 16
4(4) + 4 = 16 + 4 = 20
...
```

As you can see, both selectors will match the same elements as above. In this case, there is no difference.

Comment: I just thought I would add, if you are doing something such as only the fourth then you would need something such as `tr td:nth-child(4)`. **Note the lack of any n within brackets**

Comment: please note: This works only on element selectors (div, td, img etc), not on class selector like .this

Comment: @Panique: I think you're confusing `:nth-child()` with `:nth-of-type()`.

Comment: I created an interactive demo to visually explain how nth-child(n) works: http://xengravity.com/demo/nth-child/.  I found the w3 spec to be particularly daunting to beginners on which syntax is allowed; specifically their 'Lexical scanner' section.

Comment: @xengravity: Thanks for sharing! I agree, the grammar isn't beginner-friendly as it was written with implementers in mind and not authors. The spec does provide a number of examples of how to write the syntax, but without accompanying visuals.

Answer (score 30):

```
div:nth-child(4n+4)
```

See: http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Answer (score 22):

You need the correct argument for the [`nth-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) pseudo class.

- The argument should be in the form of `an + b` to match every a<sup>th</sup> child starting from b.
- Both `a` and `b` are optional integers and both can be zero or negative.

  - If `a` is zero then there is no *"every a<sup>th</sup> child"* clause.
  - If `a` is negative then matching is done backwards starting from `b`.
  - If `b` is zero or negative then it is possible to write equivalent expression using positive `b` e.g. `4n+0` is same as `4n+4`. Likewise `4n-1` is same as `4n+3`.

Examples:

#### Select every 4th child (4, 8, 12, ...)

```css
li:nth-child(4n) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ol>
```

#### Select every 4th child starting from 1 (1, 5, 9, ...)

```css
li:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ol>
```

#### Select every 3rd and 4th child from groups of 4 (3 and 4, 7 and 8, 11 and 12, ...)

```css
/* two selectors are required */
li:nth-child(4n+3),
li:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ol>
```

#### Select first 4 items (4, 3, 2, 1)

```css
/* when a is negative then matching is done backwards  */
li:nth-child(-n+4) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 12):

**Try this**

```
div:nth-child(4n+4)
```