# Understanding nth-child(an + b): selector with formula in CSS3?

Tags: css, css-selectors

The `<i>` used for icons and child of the first `<div>` should have a big icon. Any other `<i>` child of any `<div>` (but not the first) should have a medium size icon:

```
<div class="row list-item">
       <div class="span1">
           <i class="icon-user"></i>
       </div>

       <div class="span3">
           <div>
               <a href="#">Main Link</a> <i class="icon-male"></i>
           </div>
           <i class="icon-mail"></i> <a href="#">Link 2</a>
           <i class="icon-mobile"></i> <a href="#">Link 3</a>
       </div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```css
.list-item > div:first-child {
    text-align: center;
}

.list-item i[class^="icon-"], .list-item[class*=" icon-"] {
    text-shadow: 3px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* Only i with icon-* class, where div is first child */
.list-item > div:first-child > i[class^="icon-"],
    .list-item > div:first-child > i[class*=" icon-"] {
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 80px;
}

/* Any i with icon-* class, where div is not first child */
.list-item > div:nth-child(1n+1) > i[class^="icon-"], 
    .list-item > div:nth-child(1n+1) > i[class*=" icon-"] {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
```

So i used offset in formula `nth-child(an + b)`, with `b = 1`. That is offset is 1 so first `<div>` should be skipped. But the first big icon is matched by the last rule. What i'm missing?

Comment: What exactly are you testing anyway? With the HTML you have provided, the properties your nth-child sets are irrelevant.

Comment: @Ana What you are talking about?

Comment: First of all, you need to have some text between your `<i>` tags in order to test the CSS you have provided. Secondly, nothing in your HTML can match `.list-item > div:nth-child(1n+1) > i[class*=" icon-"]`

Comment: @Ana text (actually an icon font) is appended before with `content` to any `<i>` by another CSS rule (not shown).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `n` in `:nth-child()` actually starts counting from zero, rather than one. From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#nth-child-pseudo):

> The value *a* can be negative, but only the positive values of *`a`*`n`+*`b`*, for `n`≥0, may represent an element in the document tree.

Although it says that the index of the first child of 1, which indeed it is, what it's referring to is the result of the formula, not the value of `n`. In other words, the first child is represented by a function of `n` that evaluates to 1, not by a function of `n` where `n = 0` or `n = 1` (whichever it starts counting at).

So the formula `:nth-child(1n+1)` (or algebraically equivalent `:nth-child(n+1)`) evaluates for `n = 0` as:

```
  1n + 1
= 1(0) + 1
= 0 + 1
= 1
```

Which results in your first `div` being matched.

You need to start from **2** for the pseudo-class notation to work as expected:

```
.list-item > div:nth-child(1n+2) > i[class^="icon-"], 
.list-item > div:nth-child(1n+2) > i[class*=" icon-"]
```

Or to make things simpler, you can opt for the [general sibling combinator `~`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) in conjunction with `:first-child` instead:

```
.list-item > div:first-child ~ div > i[class^="icon-"], 
.list-item > div:first-child ~ div > i[class*=" icon-"]
```

This has an added bonus of IE7/IE8 support, in case it matters.

Comment: @TylerH: It's been moved away from selectors-4 to css-syntax-3. I'm lazy so I'll just link to selectors-3...