# Extracting sub table from a table in imacros

Tags: imacros

This is the [webpage](https://maharerait.mahaonline.gov.in/PrintPreview/PrintPreview/UHJvamVjdElEPTIzMTUmRGl2aXNpb249NiZVc2VySUQ9OTQxNCZSb2xlSUQ9MSZBcHBJRD0yNTc2MyZBY3Rpb249U0VBUkNI) from where I'm trying to extract data
I'm just trying to extract sub table from a table under **Building Details** Category

I tried with

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H2 ATTR=TXT:Building<SP>Details
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=HTM
SET txt1 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET count_txt EVAL(("var n=\"{{txt1}}\";var a=n.match(/<table class=\"table table-bordered table-responsive table-striped\">/g) || []).length;a;")
PROMPT {{count_txt}}
```

In this code I'm first counting the occurrence of text `'<table class=\"table table-bordered table-responsive table-striped\"'`  and based on this trying to spilt the HTM and then extract the data, but this is giving me the error

```
MacroSyntaxError: wrong format of SET command, line 4 (Error code: -910)
```

I'm trying to get something like this

```
        Sr.No.  Project_Name        Name                   Number of Basement's   Number of Plinth  Number of Podium's   Number_of_Slab_of_Super_Structure   Number_of_Stilts   Number_of Open_Parking   Number_of_Closed_Parking   Sr.No.  Apartment_Type   Carpet_Area_(in Sqmts)   Number_of_Apartment   Number_of_Booked_Apartment
          1     SERENE CITY    SERENE CITY A-01/A-02        0                     1                 0                              2                               0              0                       0                        1     VILLA 2BHK   234.3                                2                          0
          2     SERENE CITY    SERENE CITY A-03/A-04        0                    1                  0                              2                             0                0                       0                        1     VILLA 2BHK                 234.3                  2                          0
```

Till the records are there...
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using I macros it will be very tedious to do, since there is only one table and there is a repeating pattern, I have written some css in which you can get only the lines you want through copy paste.

**Explanation:**

The row you need is in the series 1,5,9,...... hence I use the nth-child selector(check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576324/understanding-nth-childan-b-selector-with-formula-in-css3)) which will display only the wanted row. Then the all tr inside the table is set to display none, which will hide it.

```
tbody > tr:nth-child(4n+2) {
    display: table !important;
}
tbody > tr {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: @deepesh does this answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

This should work ("count_txt" must be defined previously, "m" is number of the table with respective class, "i" is number of row within the table in this case), but you will need to add headers for columns manually:

```
for(m=1;m<=count_txt;m++){
    var macro;
    var rows=10;
    var tag = "TAG XPATH=\".//body/descendant::table[@class="table table-bordered table-striped"][{{m}}]/tbody/tr[{{i}}]/td[3]\" EXTRACT=TXT"
    macro =  "CODE:";
    macro += tag;
    iimPlay("CODE:ADD !EXTRACT {{!m}}");//row#
    for(i=1;i<=rows;i++){
    iimSet("i",i);
    iimPlay(macro);//extract data
    }
    iimPlay("CODE:SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=MyTable.csv");//save
    }
```