# Selecting every 4th <div>

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a long line of DIVs and I need to change the padding on every 4th DIV using the nth-child selector, but I am having problems getting it to work at all.

Here is my css:

```css
.content_tab {
    width: 220px;
    height: 340px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #0F0;
}
.content_tab:nth-child(4){
    background-color: #F00;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

and here is my HTML:

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="content_tab"></div>
    <div class="content_tab"></div>
    <div class="content_tab"></div>
    <div class="content_tab"></div>
    <div class="content_tab"></div>
    <div class="content_tab"></div>
    <div class="content_tab"></div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css

Comment: What browser are you using?  Have you tested it in one not owned by Bill Gates?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select every Nth element in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should change

```
.content_tab:nth-child(4){
```

To

```
.content_tab:nth-child(4n){
```

As explained here http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Or if you do not want the first div to be selected, you need

```
.content_tab:nth-child(4n+4){
```

Answer (score 12):

```
.content div:nth-child(4n) {  /* selects 4, 8, 12, 16, etc. */
    padding: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y6vfg/1/

Or if you want every fourth element starting from the **first** you can use:

```
.content div:nth-child(4n + 1) { /* selects 1, 5, 9, 13 .. */
    padding: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y6vfg/7/

Answer (score 5):

To get every 4th element in the selector use `4n`

```css
.content_tab:nth-child(4n){
    background-color: #F00;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YPRB9/)

Note I made the div sizes smaller in the fiddle so it was easier to see it working.