# How to select 1st, 4th, 7th element and so on?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How could I select the 1st, 4th, 7th elements and so on ?! also how to select the 3rd, 6th, 9th and so on?

the pattern is selecting and element then leaving two and selecting the third. I know I should use `:nth-child`, but I don't know how exactly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select every Nth element in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To style the first, fourth, seventh (and so on) elements, the easiest method is, with CSS, to use the following (I'm assuming you're working with `li` elements, but obviously adapt to your use-case):

```
ul {
    counter-reset: lis;
}

li::after {
    counter-increment: lis;
    content: counter(lis, decimal);
}

li:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background-color: #f90;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RbH9N/).

References:

- [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).
- [`:nth-child()`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3anth-child).

Comment: Gahhhhhh I Ctrl+R'd for this one and everything haha! +1

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187075/going-to-any-question-on-the-site-brings-an-error-page

Comment: Oh, I only just came back from dinner. Um, sorry... =(

Comment: Haha no worries. That is pro timing on your part :D

Comment: Well *brushing nails on lapels* it's good to have some skills... ;)

Comment: What can I say? It made copy-pasting the `li` elements easier, and meant I didn't have to edit in numbers... ;)

Comment: Works like magic with LIs, It never seemed to work with DIVs :)

Comment: It certainly should. Can you show the html (and link to a jsFiddle demo that shows the code) not-working?

Comment: Some useful visual supporting resources http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/ , http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/ and http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/ .

Answer (score 2):

I think, this is easier than the accepted answer:

```
li:nth-child(3n - 2) {
    padding-left: 0; // etc
}
```