# Creating menus with HMENU in TYPO3 using TypoScript

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript

My aim is to create a menu in TYPO3 6, which can have multiple rows. Assuming I have 10 items that need to be listed in the menu, then 5 should be in the first row and `<br/>` after that and then the other five.

But if there are only 6, then 3 on first row then `<br>` and the next 3 on the next row.

But if there are only 2 or any number less than 4, then they should all be listed in one row

`For 10 items`

```
Item-1 Item-2 Item-3 Item-4 Item-5 
Item-6 Item-7 Item-8 Item-9 Item-10
```

`For 6 items`

```
Item-1 Item-2 Item-3 
Item-4 Item-5 Item-6

For <4 items

Item-1 Item-2 Item-3
```

but for `5 items`

```
Item-1 Item-2 Item-3 Item-4
          Item-5
```

So far, I have this:

```
lib.level1Menu = COA
lib.level1Menu {
    10 = HMENU
    10.1 = TMENU
    10.1 {
        wrap =  <center><ul><br/>|</ul></center>
        NO {
            stdWrap.cObject = COA
            stdWrap.cObject {
                10 = TEXT
                10.field = title
                if.value.data = register:count_HMENU_MENUOBJ
                if.negate = 1
                if.isLessThan.prioriCalc=1
                if.isLessThan.cObject=TEXT
                if.isLessThan.cObject.insertData=1
                if.isLessThan.cObject.value = ({register:count_menuItems}+1)/2
                wrap = <li><br/>|</li>
            }
        }
    }
    20 < .10
    20.1.wrap = <center><ul><br/>|</ul></center>
    20.1.NO.stdWrap.cObject.if.negate >
}
```

Which does not work properly.

Comment: depending on the design wouldn't it be easier (and more semantical) to give the ul a width and float the li's inside via CSS?

Comment: Other option is using JS for setting the divider in required place and/or writing custom plugin, it will be rather difficult task to do that with the pure TS

Comment: Just an idea, not tested: Maybe you can cook up something using optionSplit: http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/optionSplit

Comment: I would suggest using the CSS approach with float and with (comment of konsolenfreddy) or the :nth-child selector to select every 6th element and use clear: both on it. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css

Comment: Yes, it makes more sense to manage the menus under CSS, but was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do it in TS. Thanks for the help everyone :)