# Style every third element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I style every third element with plain CSS.

I have seen questions like this, but they involve javascript. I want a plain CSS solution. I know I can use `even` or `odd` with `:nth-child` but `:nth-child(third)` doesn't work neither does `:nth-child(3)`

Example:

```
<section>
  <div class="someclass"></div>             STYLE
  <div id="someId"></div>                   DON'T STYLE
  <div class="someotherclass"></div>        DON'T STYLE
  <div id="someotherId"></div>              STYLE
  <div class="someclass"></div>             DON'T STYLE
  <div id="someId"></div>                   DON'T STYLE
  <div class="someotherclass"></div>        STYLE
</section>
```

Is this possible with CSS - no javascript or jQuery?

Comment: The only way to guarantee full support for this is to process this specific part of HTML server-side, using logic there to add the styles in the manner that you want. That eliminates the problem of browsers not supporting `nth-child`.

Comment: If there were an older way to do this in CSS, why did they invent `:nth-child`?

Comment: Why would you care today for compatibility with `IE 8`?

Comment: @AdamS can you write a better answer, I might accept it.

Comment: You should award the bounty to JoshC (unless you're looking for a JavaScript solution).

Comment: @AdamS because a *lot* of people still use it in the US and around the world (XP anyone?) asker should find or create a poly fill for the desired behavior.

Comment: you could always just add a class "third" with associated style and add it to each third div as you render them into the page.

Comment: Thanks to IE all the good that CSS3 and HTML5 do is absolutely worthless. It adds to the developer woes, having them write archaic CSS that runs good on IE. To all you IE 8 users, I say what is stopping you from upgrading to IE9/10. You are surfing net and you can't upgrade your browser. Derric unless you are paid enough for this, forget the IE8 users let them suffer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select every Nth element in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is possible with **pure CSS**. No javascript needed.

Use the [**nth-child selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child).<sup>1</sup>

```
section > div:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background:red;
}
```

Where '1' is where the style starts, and 3 indicates that it should style every third element. It is explained much better [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child).

[**jsFiddle demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/eRzPB/).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Note - as other people have mentioned this is [**not fully supported**](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3) by IE8 and down.</sub>

Comment: Would `nth-child(4n+1)` style every forth element?

Comment: @DerrickJackson You only needed to modify the fiddle to see: http://jsfiddle.net/eRzPB/1/

Comment: @JohnH oh cool. and what if I want it not to start at the first element?

Comment: @JohnH you should put that example as an answer

Comment: @DerrickJackson I shouldn't, because JoshC has provided all the necessary information for you, and others, to play with to see how it works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37556/discussion-between-derrick-jackson-and-john-h)

Comment: As a reminder to everyone, nth-child (and last-child) are not supported in IE8 or lower

Answer (score 8):

**IE Support via Libraries**

If it is IE support you are looking for, there is a wonderful library called [Selectivzr](http://selectivizr.com/) that enables CSS3 selectors on IE versions 6-8.

**Hack that doesn't help IE, but is done without use of :nth-child**

Otherwise all I can offer is an ugly hack using the `+` adjacent sibling selector (Defined by CSS2 standards, but not available by default in IE8 or below)

```
div {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
}

div + div,
div + div + div + div + div { width: 100px }

div + div + div + div,
div + div + div + div + div + div + div { width: 40px }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NXAfN/1/)

This pattern could be generated with most CSS Precompilers (ie [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)), but is limited by the amount of elements you wish to have.

**Conclusion**

If all you're looking for is IE support; then I strongly recommend using a library such as [Selectivzr](http://selectivizr.com/). This will spare you some IE6-8 headaches.

If I have any epiphanies in regards to a better solution, I'll post.

Comment: Best cross browser solution. We can't unfortunately drop IE8 yet.

Comment: This also requires plugin support from plugins like jquery or prototype.. I would have used straight my own javascript code instead though if I don't want to include other plugins.

Answer (score 4):

```
section div:nth-child(3n+3) {  
    color: #ccc;
}
```

selected elements :

```
(3xn)+3 :
(3 x 0) + 3 = 3 = 3rd Element
(3 x 1) + 3 = 6 = 6th Element
(3 x 2) + 3 = 9 = 9th Element
etc.
```

you can read it as follow :

**(select all third element) starting at 3**

here you have all what you need as **DEMO**

http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

read more here 
http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Select Only Odd or Even:

```
section div:nth-child(odd) {

}

section div:nth-child(even) {

    }
```

Select Only The First Five

```
div:nth-child(-n+5) {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Pure CSS, No Javascript, with IE7/8 Support

**Requires Change of HTML, or...**

You must either explicitly set some class on the elements you want changed in your HTML, whether dynamically through server side script counting, or manually by hard coding.

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eRzPB/10/)

*HTML*

```
<section>
  <div class="someclass explicitClass"></div>
  <div id="someId"></div>
  <div class="someotherclass"></div>
  <div id="someotherId" class="explicitClass"></div>
  <div class="someclass"></div>
  <div id="someId"></div>
  <div class="someotherclass explicitClass"></div>   
</section>
```

*CSS*

```css
.explicitClass {
    your-property-to-change: your-value-desired;
}
```

**... Requires Extensive CSS Markup**

Or you must generate CSS that is "counting" for you in a bulky way. As Indy noted in his answer (not sure why he stated adjacent sibling is "not available by default in IE8 or below," as [that is incorrect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)), this could be handled through a CSS preprocessor, but even then, you really don't want to go this route unless you have a *very limited number* of elements, probably no more than what you posted for your example. If there were hundreds of elements, this is not practical. This solution requires no change in your HTML.

[**DEMO Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eRzPB/11/)

*CSS*

```css
section div:first-child,
section div:first-child + div + div + div,
section div:first-child + div + div + div + div + div + div {
    your-property-to-change: your-value-desired;
}
```

### Ultimately, I Agree with JoshC and Indy

I've offered the above answers just to show what you must do if you really want what you say you want. If it were me, unless it was absolutely vital to have these change of styles on every third element (so javascript turned off is fatal to the whole scheme; and even that could be worked around to restyle for non-javascript), I would use JoshC's answer as your CSS, and then use some form of javascript solution to make it backwards compatible (as Indy noted, or any other form of javascript solution).

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
.my-class:nth-child(odd) {}
```

or

```
.my-class:nth-child(2n+1) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
section > div:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background:red;
}
```

This style is good for fixing your problem, but '>' this symbol, isn't supported for old browsers, for example: IE5, IE6, IE7 . . .

But I prefer this way, without '>' symbol

```
section div:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: Right, but you are still using `nth-child`, which is also, **NOT** supported by IE8, 7, etc.

Comment: I wrote code about old browsers, but I think IE isn't browser, We must write code for Firefox,Chrome,Opera,Safari and IE(Only new versions).

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is

```
section div:nth-child(3n+1) {  
    color: #ccc;
}
```

The  above code styles every 3rd element starting from first element as requested.
Change the number after **'+ sign'** to set the starting element.
Change the number before **n charecter** to set the elements after to be styled

Answer (score 0):

With pure css this can be easily done. You can define [CSS Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and change the desired child property. For your case below is suitable.

```
section > div:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background: green;
}
```

How this work.

[Pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-elements)

Here above work like below

```
if n = 0 then 3*0 + 1 = 1
if n = 1 then 3*1 + 1 = 4
if n = 2 then 3*2 + 1 = 7
if n = 3 then 3*3 + 1 = 10
...........
```

If you want every 3rd element then your css looks like

```
section > div:nth-child(3n+3) {
    background: green;
}
```

Here above work like below

```
if n = 0 then 3*0 + 3 = 3
if n = 1 then 3*1 + 3 = 6
if n = 2 then 3*2 + 3 = 9
if n = 3 then 3*3 + 3 = 12
...........
```