# Select every third elements in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have an `unorder list` and every list item have a `div`.

My `HTML` is something like this.

```
<ul>
    <li>
      <div>.....</div>
    </li>   
    <li>
      <div>.....</div>
    </li>   
    <li>
      <div>.....</div>
    </li>   
    <li>
      <div>.....</div>
    </li>   
    <li>
      <div>.....</div>
    </li>   
    <li>
      <div>.....</div>
    </li>   
    <li>
      <div>.....</div>
    </li>   
    <li>
      <div>.....</div>
    </li>   
    <li>
      <div>.....</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have added bottom and right `margin` to every `div`s (I am targeting divs' which are directly inside `li` elements. Now I need to remove margin from every third `div` elements. (3rd, 6th, and 9th etc..)

This is my `CSS` but its not working for me.

```
li > div {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  padding: 10px;
}

li > div:nth-of-type(3n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** I also tried with `:nth-child` selector. but no luck.

Hope somebody will help me. 
Thank you.

Comment: The title is confusing which was leading me to close this question as a kind of duplicate of [Style every third element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860786/style-every-third-element/18860795#18860795).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were trying to select every third `div` element within a `li`. Since there is only one `div` element within each `li`, none were being selected. You should select every third `li` element instead:

```
li:nth-of-type(3n) > div {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/616Lkxgx/)

Answer (score 3):

```
li:nth-of-type(3n)  > div{
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `nth-child` to `li` not for `div`

```
li:nth-child(3n) > div {
  margin-right: 0px; 
  /* other styles comes here */
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/0awqonp5/1/)