# Grouping "a" tags in to a li by 3 using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to take list of links and group them together in to a UL by groups of 3 using jQuery.  I'm having a rough time as the loops never seem to work out.  The

Present state is:

```
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
<a href="#">Link 4</a>
<a href="#">Link 5</a>
<a href="#">Link 6</a>
<a href="#">Link 7</a>
<a href="#">Link 8</a>
```

I want the future state to be:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
    <a href="#">Link 6</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Link 7</a>
    <a href="#">Link 8</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't think that setup makes sense (maybe you mean to replace the `<li>`s with `<ul>`s and the `<a>`s with `<li>`s). BTW, SO has a nice new layout.

Comment: No - the setup is correct.  For my application I have a slider that needs three linked images in each slide.  Each slide is an <li> element.  Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: yeah sure, I'll write an answer in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var as = $('#HomepageSlider a');
as.wrapAll("<ul></ul>");
var count = 0;
var li;
as.each(function(i, obj) {
  if (count % 3 == 0)
  {
    $('#HomepageSlider ul').append('<li></li>');
    li = $($('#HomepageSlider ul li')[count/3]);
  }
  li.append(obj);
  count++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="HomepageSlider">
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
<a href="#">Link 4</a>
<a href="#">Link 5</a>
<a href="#">Link 6</a>
<a href="#">Link 7</a>
<a href="#">Link 8</a>
</div>
```

Comment: this is great @shahar but how could I put the new UL in my div?  For example, I have a div on the page called <div id="HomepageSlider"><!-- slider ul here --></div>

Comment: This is so close @shahar but for some reason it is appending to the first ul on the page.  It looks like it has something to do with this line: $("ul").append('<li></li>');.  Is there a way to append it directly to the current ul?  When I replaced it with $(this) I had the same results. Thoughts?  Thank you for your help with this!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
$('a:nth-child(3n + 1)').filter(function () {
    $(this).nextAll(':lt(2)').andSelf().wrapAll('<li></li>');
    return $(this);
}).parent().siblings('li').wrapAll('<ul></ul>');
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2p92jzyv/)

Just [select every third element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860786/style-every-third-element/18860795#18860795) using `:nth-child(3n + 1)`. Filter through those elements, and select 2 succeeding siblings elements and use [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) to wrap them.

Then wrap all the `li` elements in a `ul`.