# Want to specify that every third picture in column had specific size

Tags: javascript

I have 4 columns with pictures inside. I want that when users will upload pictures, every third and fourth picture had specific sizes. Any suggestions on how to do this??

Since I am new, I could not post any solution I tried.

Comment: [SO search result for ... "\[css\] every third element"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+every+third+element) ... first pick from that list ... [*Style every third element?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860786/style-every-third-element) ... @WebQuestions ... your problem most probably will be solved best by CSS.

Comment: any code you have tried ?

Comment: I tried to find solution but without any result

Answer (score -1):

Try using css:

```
li:nth-child(3), li:nth-child(4) { 
  background-color: Blue;
}
```

This css will only change background color of 3rd and 4th `<li>` tags

Comment: Please try again, both selectors are not correct for many reasons.