# Line Between List Entries Spanning Multiple Columns

Tags: css

I have a list with a simple CSS style to add horizontal lines between list elements like so:

```
li:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

This works great, except that now I want to have the list split between two columns, which I'm doing like so:

```
ul {
  column-count: 2;
  column-width: 50%;
}
```

The problem with this is that the list item at the bottom of the left-hand column has a bottom border, because of course the `:not(:last-child)` condition sees the entire list as one contiguous sequence, rather than two separate ones.

Is there a way I can structure a CSS rule such that it will not apply to the last element of each column in a multi-column element, or some workaround I can use instead?

In terms of workarounds, I could of course just split my list in two during page generation (*i.e.* in my PHP script) but I'm specifically interested whether there's a pure CSS solution.

For clarification, here's a picture of how the above looks:
[image: Current Appearance]

What I'm looking to do is get rid of the line under the fourth element in a general purpose way (i.e- without using `:not(:nth-child(4))` or such).

Comment: Please post a picture of the desire output.

Comment: @Stickers: I think I've managed to add an image showing the current appearance; what I want to do is remove the line from under the fourth item, but in a general purpose way (i.e- without using `:not(:nth-child(4))` or similar.

Comment: I doubt if that can be done with css, similar question  https://stackoverflow.com/q/23082368/483779

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this but referring to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child, you could try something like:

```
li:not(:nth-last-child(1)),
li:not(:nth-last-child(2)) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to do anything to me; what is the intended outcome of it?