# Selecting every third element except for a few (in unordered list)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I select every other 3rd element in an unordered list like below? I have a random amount of `<li>`'s but I need every other 3rd so for example the third, the ninth, the fifteenth, etc. is such a thing possible in html or css or javascript?

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Comment: I dont understand your question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select every Nth element in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css)

Comment: @Greg: This one's a little bit different.

Comment: First, that's every sixth, not every third. Second, have you tried anything?

Comment: @BoltClock how so? every n starting at m is addressed in the answers for that question.

Comment: this smells like homework ...

Comment: @Greg: In this case, n isn't equal to m, and that's the heart of the problem. I realize the duplicate header says "This question may already have an answer here" but I've always looked at questions rather than answers when considering duplicates, and I don't believe my own answer addresses the issue here sufficiently because the context given by the question is different.

Comment: @BoltClock Fair enough :) Will keep that in mind going forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're actually looking to select every *sixth* element, but starting from the third:

```
ul li:nth-child(6n+3)
```

Comment: thats what I wanted. thanl you!!