# all elements in class show as even

Tags: html, css

On my webpage there are DIV's that are created dynamically with the class of jOUT.
I want to change the color of every other iteration of the class.

I'm trying to do it this way:

```
.jOUT:nth-child(even){
   background:#eeefff;
}

.jOUT:nth-child(odd){
   background:#cccffe;
}
```

My HTML is as follows:

```
  <div id="outData">
    <input type="hidden" name="outDivider" value="-------">
    <div class="jOUT isOpaque">
      <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="outDivider" value="-------">
    <div class="jOUT isOpaque">
      <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="outDivider" value="-------">
    <div class="jOUT">
      <!-- ... -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

Full HTML [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p2zgn79r)

But it's not working. What's really weird is that using the console in Chrome, when I select each jOUT, it shows ALL of them as having the "even" attribute.
I thought for sure that I had invalid CSS or HTML but I can't find it. It has to be something I'm doing, but what? I guess what I'm asking for is an idea for a place to start looking for the problem. I've verified the CSS using w3c CSS verification, and the HTML using HTML Tidy.

Comment: try clearing your cache

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your markup, but it's nth-**child** and not nth-occurrence.  I imagine your elements are each wrapped in some other element making them all the 2nd children of their parent or something?  Please add the html to your question.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/96LLzLtc/

Comment: here is a jsFiddle using my code  http://jsfiddle.net/p2zgn79r/

Comment: @shawn Your `jOUT` elements are the 2nd 4th and 6th children of their parent element.   Those are all even.

Comment: Why do you have hidden input's with a value of `-----`, they get counted in the nth-child calcs

Comment: Even and odd are not calculated only for elements with your class. They're in relation to all siblings within a given parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work here:

```
.jOUT:nth-child(4n){
   background:#eeefff;
}
```

**[More on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css)**

This is somewhat fragile, though. A better approach is to add an alternative style class on those elements, possibly via your server-side app.

Answer (score 2):

Your current CSS is working as it should, because you're targeting ALL children (including `input`); which means, in this scenario, all your `div.jOUT` are even - you should rather use `:nth-of-type`, which will only target instances of `div.jOUT` ...

```
.jOUT:nth-of-type(even){
   background:#eeefff;
}

.jOUT:nth-of-type(odd){
   background:#cccffe;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jayx/wqmd2nkb/) fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Your `input[name="outDivider"]` elements are in the way, thus making every `jOUT` element even. Here's a [working pen](http://codepen.io/caio1511/pen/gbQdVX) where I took them out and made the selector work properly. I also changed the colors, so it's easier to see.

**Edit:** @isherwood beat me to it, but if this `input[name="outDivider"]` elements are absolutely necessary, his solution works best!

Comment: yes the outDivider was requested by the server-side guy so I hope it's necessary for something and not superfluous