# Removing margin for specific div

Tags: html, css

[image]

This screenshot is from the website. As you can see I print boxes on the screen, and right after a box, another one comes. Every box has float: left, and margin-right: 5px;

My problem is I need to remove margin-right: 5px after the 3th box, which is the last box that my container can hold. So the bosex will be like:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

So, for 3,6,9 etc.. I gotta remove the margin-right. As you can see from the image, there is margin-right in the last box (you will recognize if you compare it to the blue line above them.)

I know there is :lastchild:after but it will have an affect on the last box only. I need it to be efective every last box of the each line. Thank you.

Comment: Try looking into `nth-child` or `nth-of-type`. Without seeing your code we can't be more specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select every Nth element in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created an interactive demo to visually explain how nth-child(n) works:
http://xengravity.com/demo/nth-child/

Here is a snippet that will work for your situation:

```css
.container {clear:both;}
.container div {background:yellow; width:25px; float:left;}
.container div:nth-child(3n) {background:red;}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div></div>
<div class="container"><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div></div>
<div class="container"><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div></div>
```

As you can see, in the snippet I am only applying the red background to the third element in each row.  You will want to change the property from background to margin instead for your purposes.

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way, I don't know why but (4n) works for me, not (3n). Although I have 3 blocks.

Comment: I would need to see your code to accurately explain why.  My assumption is that you may have `div`'s for each row and a `div` for each number. If you are not specifying your selector to be inside of that div, technically the "third" number of each row is the 4th div.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a selector for every third element:

```
.box:nth-child(3n) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nth-child(3n)`, where `3n` stands for elements `3x1(3)`, `3x2(6)`, `3x3(9)` and so on:

```
div:nth-child(3n) {margin-right: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the nth-child property and target the 3,6,9 child like below.

```
divname:nth-child(3n){margin-right:0;}
```