# CSS - style element after given element

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to style element after element? 
For example i have this:

```
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li class="hiden">B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li class="hiden">E</li>
  <li class="hiden">E</li>
  <li class="hiden">E</li>
  <li>F</li>
</ul>
```

I want every first li after li.hiden to have border-top.

li + li.hiden works only on first element in ul.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To target first `li` after `li.hiden` you should use `li.hiden + li` selector:

```css
li.hiden + li {
    border-top: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li class="hiden">B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li class="hiden">E</li>
  <li>F</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `li.hiden + li:not(.hiden)` is what i wanted, thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you..

https://jsfiddle.net/0c5eu92w/

```
    li.hiden + li{border-top:1px solid #ccc;}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about CSS3 selector? Try this:

> :nth-child(2n)

You'll find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css).