# Selecting every fourth element inside another element

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#>
        <img src=" #">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to select every fourth image tag inside these list-items? I know i could just select every fourth li element because im looking to float them but is there a way around it so i can seelct every fourth image element inside the list-items?

Comment: Didnt understand the Qstn!

Comment: I think this will help you on your way:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule will let you select the images in every 4th `<li>`:

```
li:nth-of-type(4n) a img{
    /* CSS Here */
}
```

Comment: All the other jquery methods work but i'd rather use css for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

by using nth-child selector `ul li:nth-child(4n) a img` try this code to select every 4th `img` tag

```
ul li:nth-child(4n) a img{
//custom css here
}
```

```css
ul li:nth-child(4n) a img{background:red;height:100px;width:100px;}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="#">
      </a>
    </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="#">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="#">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="#">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="#">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="#">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="#">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="#">
      </a>
    </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="#">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="#">
     </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="#">
     </a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href="#">
       <img src="#">
     </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector like following.

```js
$('ul li:nth-child(4n) img').css('border', '2px solid red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
        <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [:eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/#index) selector. It has starting index 0 same as array.

```
$("ul li").eq(3).find('img').css("color", "red");
```

OR

```
$("ul li:eq(3)")find('img').css("color", "red");
```