# nth-child advanced logic selection

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I apologise in advance that I have not made good progress on this matter so I dont have a Fiddle nor Codepen.

I do have the following layout (below) that I wish to achieve.

My only question is how I select two elements in a row and then another two elements in a row so I can style them accordingly. Keeping in mind that the first-child will need to be separately selected.

The last picture is just to show them in a horizontal order to easier understand what I wish to achieve :)

Last note is that I will be using Packery to enable the smug fit in case you are wondering

Thank you!

[image: Nth logic]

Comment: You will have to do some simple maths in your head. From the top of mine, you can select the first on after the first element in this pattern using `:nth-child(1+4n-3)`, the second one using `:nth-child(1+4n-2)` etc... However, without posting any code - not even HTML - it feels more like you are asking us to develop it for you, which is not the purpose of this site...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select every Nth element in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child):

> The `:nth-child(an+b)` CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has `an+b-1` siblings before it in the document tree, for a given positive or zero value for `n`, and has a parent element. More simply stated, the selector matches a number of child elements whose numeric position in the series of children matches the pattern `an+b`.

Therefore, to match the blue squares (first and fourth for every quadruplet), you can use the following:

```
:nth-child(4n+1), :nth-child(4n)
```

and for the orange rectangles (second and third for every quadruplet):

```
:nth-child(4n+2), :nth-child(4n+3) { ... }
```

Also make sure to add a selector before the `:nth-child` to make it more specific. For instance, use something like `div:nth-child(...)` (see example below) or a class/id selector for most accurate results.

---

Working example:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
div:nth-child(4n+1), div:nth-child(4n) {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}
div:nth-child(4n+2), div:nth-child(4n+3) {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</span>
```

---

Also see [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) and [CSSTricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know is to "cheat" with css using twice the same class :

```
div:nth-child(4n){background-color:red;}
div:nth-child(4n+1){background-color:red;}
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/t1zwa8bt/)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You can use a comma separator to add the same style to multiple selectors. See: [CSS Selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/611/selectors)

Comment: Yeah I usually use it but as OP looks quite new with CSS, I used the easiest way to explain it.