# How to exclude nth selector?

Tags: html, css

Let's say i have this:

[image]

i want to add green color for each div except a div with a multiple of 3? Is it possible to do that with `nth-child()` or maybe with another way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select every Nth element in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
:not(:nth-child(3n))
```

Comment: Thank you sir @samir Chahine

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `:nth-child()` and `:not()` pseudo-class which will select all divs except every 3rd `div`

```css
div:not(:nth-child(3n)) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
```

Another way is to select `div:nth-child(3n + 1)` and `div:nth-child(3n + 2)`

```css
div:nth-child(3n +1),
div:nth-child(3n + 2) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir @Nenad Vracar

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine

```
div:nth-child(3n) {
background: black;
```

}