# nth-child every eight (8)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to repeat a pattern every eight elements like this using nth-child.

■□■□

□■□■

I've been trying to figure out a formula for this but I don't seem to get it right.

```css
section {
  width: 220px;
}
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

div:nth-child(4n), div:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select every Nth element in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css)

Comment: In the future please don't adjust your question to invalidate existing answers. If you end up changing your code to fit a solution, that's fine, but existing solutions to the code you posted originally can look out of place and lose their context if you change your question's code substantively.

Comment: Hi TylerH. I realized the markup was wrong, so I had to change it in order to have any success in getting a right answer. I understand what you mean though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have to keep the `<br>` element then you don't want to use `nth-child` as the `<br>` will count as a child. Instead you can use `nth-of-type`:

```
div:nth-of-type(5n+1),div:nth-of-type(5n+3) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Example:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
}

div:nth-of-type(5n+1),div:nth-of-type(5n+3) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <br>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Based on the updated information in your question it looks like the better solution is `div:nth-of-type(8n+1), div:nth-of-type(8n+3),div:nth-of-type(8n+6), div:nth-of-type(8n+8) { background-color: green; }`

```css
body {
  font-size: 10pt;
}

section {
  width: 220px;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

div:nth-of-type(8n+1),
div:nth-of-type(8n+3),
div:nth-of-type(8n+6),
div:nth-of-type(8n+8) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>Should repeat here</div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>Should repeat here</div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi @j08691. Sorry, the <br> should not be there and therefore won't work as expected. I've updated the snippet. The pattern needs to repeat every eighth element because the number of elements is unknow. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @fudgemugabe My answer should work with or without the `<br>` in your previous example.

Comment: I think we're almost there but the pattern isn't repeating. It should repeat in a checkered pattern. Jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/hs8pj8uo/. Thank you.

Comment: I see. Then you may need this `div:nth-of-type(8n+1), div:nth-of-type(8n+3),div:nth-of-type(8n+6), div:nth-of-type(8n+8) {
  background-color: green;
}` See https://jsfiddle.net/24ummstc/

Comment: Excellent. I've marked this as the answer. Maybe your last comment should be included your code snippet for others to see later? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I'll do that. Let me know if you need an explanation about the selectors.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div:nth-child(8n + 1) { background-color: green; }
div:nth-child(8n + 2) { background-color: orange; }
div:nth-child(8n + 3) { background-color: aqua; }
div:nth-child(8n + 4) { background-color: red; }

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
}

section {
  width: 220px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo