# How to individually target nested images?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-selectors

I'm trying to style a random set of images based on their chronological appearance on the page using CSS only without any html classes ([old demo](https://jsfiddle.net/42438crq/3/)).

Since all images in that section are links, I wrapped `<a>` ...`</a>` around the `img` tags but now the css selections are broken!

I have tried various selectors but all are broken (not selected, not correct background color applied):

```
sponsor img:nth-child(1)
sponsor img:nth-of-type(1)
sponsor a img:nth-child(1)
a img:nth-child(1)
```

[JSFIDDLE Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m0ymv1ex/3/) of the broken chronological selectors. What have I overlooked? Thanks!

Comment: You need to just replace your img: with a:.. and add img after nth-child()

Comment: `img` is now a direct child of your anchor not `sponsor`, there is only one child, think it as `img:nth-child(1)` for every anchor. So `img:nth-child(n)` will not work if `n !== 1`. What you need to do is change your selectors like @Garric15 proposes below in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By wrapping your images in a `<a>`...`</a>` tag, the `img:nth-child(1)` is not valid. You should use the `:nth-child` property on the `a` tag instead :

```
sponsor a:nth-child(1) img{width:100%; background: Fuchsia}
sponsor a:nth-child(2) img{width: 49%; background: YellowGreen}
...
```

[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m0ymv1ex/5/)

Comment: Thanks awesome the demo is very clear and demonstrates how this ought to be used in a correct way! Will these "complex" css rules not slow down modern browsers?

Answer (score 3):

The [**`nth-child()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class targets all children of the same parent.

Since the `img` elements were the children of `sponsor`, `nth-child()` worked.

But when you wrapped each `img` in an anchor element, they became children of `a` and no longer children of `sponsor`. Therefore, `nth-child()` failed.

With each `img` now existing as the first, last and only child of `a`, targeting them with `nth-child()` is pointless.

To fix your layout, `nth-child()` needs to target the new children of `sponsor` – the anchors.

Instead of this:

```
sponsor img:nth-child(2)
```

Try this:

```
sponsor > a:nth-child(2) > img
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael_B for your awesome explanation +1 very clear

Comment: @Garric15, Is there also a way to group the styles for children [1],   [2-3],  [4-5] and [6-9] ? in other words grouping of the selectors `nth-child(1){}`,  `nth-child(2-3){}`, `nth-child(4-5)`, `nth-child(6-9)`  (Or shall I ask this as a separate question?)

Comment: Sam, you're welcome. Glad I could help.. With regard to your question in the comment above, it's a bit involved, so you may want to post a new question. Also, see my answer here for guidance. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45038349/3597276

Comment: great! I will post a separate question about the grouping. for now one final question: what will the difference be when considering `element > a:nth-child(1) > img` (your answer) versus  `element a:nth-child(1) img`  (the other answer)?

Comment: Unless you're talking about tens of thousands of lines of code that are being targeted, the difference in performance is negligible. However, I generally use the child combinator (`>`) wherever possible as it is, theoretically, more efficient. The browser does less work and is, again, theoretically, faster. ([**More info.**](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+descendant+vs+child+performance))

Comment: Agreed. Forget performance for a second. You had a *reason* to use `>`, please share why (one or more reasons) you chose for `>`  :-)  Thanks

Comment: I only use the descendant combinator when I'm targeting elements beyond the children. That's what it's for. I'm targeting "descendants"... I always try to use the child combinator when targeting the children. That's what it is designed for: Targeting only the children. CSS provides a multitude of ways to target an element. I tend to adhere to a principle of "intended purpose". It's not really a performance matter for me, but more of an effort to use the best available method and write clean code.