# Add class every nth in a loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a class "first" on the first column of five columns in a wordpress loop. Please see sample below

```
<div class="box first"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box first"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

I tried doing something like this but it doesnt seem to work

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );      
if ( have_posts() ) :               
echo '<div class="row">';           
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();        
for ($i=0; $i<$num_list; $i++) {
    if ($i % 5 == 1) {
         echo '<div class="box first"></div>';
    } else {
         echo '<div class="box"></div>';
    }
}   
endwhile;
echo '</div>';
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: what does "doesnt seem to work" actually mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select every Nth element in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css)

Comment: need to be done in php not css

Answer (score 1):

Using modulo is a good choice. But should be compared to zero instead of one :

```
for ($i=0; $i<$num_list; $i++) {
    if ($i % 5 == 0) {
         echo '<div class="box first"></div>';
    } else {
         echo '<div class="box"></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesnt appear to add the class

Comment: Please check $num_list value, debug while loop. Your problem is with loops conditions. Check them

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result without adding a special class, but setting a rule that matches every 5th element. Here's an example:

```css
.box{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 3px;
}
.box:nth-child(5n+1){
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: thanks however there are ready made class so I need to do it via php and add class not create class