# Select child elements under 2 levels from the parent div

Tags: css

Am currently having a code something like below to render 9 boxes like a rubix cube

```css
#child {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(235, 26, 224, 0.829);
}

#outer {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner">
            <div id="child"></div>
            <div id="child"></div>
            <div id="child"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="child"></div>
            <div id="child"></div>
            <div id="child"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="child"></div>
            <div id="child"></div>
            <div id="child"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Am trying to assign different colors to the 9 `divs` using `nth-child`, but the browser is considering the `divs` as 3 different elements and not 9, as there is an intermediate div `#inner` which is another parent of the `#child`

```css
#child:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: blue;
}
#child:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: green;
}
#child:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: red;
}
#child:nth-child(5) {
    background-color: yellow;
}
#child:nth-child(6) {
    background-color: black;
}
/*  and so on for 9 divs  */
```

Can someone help me on this to differentiate the `#child` divs only with `CSS`

Comment: It's invalid (and poor practice) to reuse HTML `id`s

Comment: @Luke assuming that i removed all `ids` and replaced with `classes`, whats the way?

Comment: Just give each square its own ID and set a color on it. Why even both with nth-child since you need to set nine distinct colors?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css/3462301#3462301

Comment: @Paulie_D these are not related to this question. They talk about immediate child of the parent and not below 2 levels

Comment: They explain how `nth-child` works...that's all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to select the parent before selecting the children:

```css
.inner div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

/* The first inner element, first child */
.inner:nth-child(1) :nth-child(1) {
  background: black;
}
/* The first inner element, second child */
.inner:nth-child(1) :nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
/* The first inner element, third child etc.. */
.inner:nth-child(1) :nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
}

.inner:nth-child(2) :nth-child(1) {
  background: green;
}
.inner:nth-child(2) :nth-child(2) {
  background: orange;
}
.inner:nth-child(2) :nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
}

.inner:nth-child(3) :nth-child(1) {
  background: pink;
}
.inner:nth-child(3) :nth-child(2) {
  background: purple;
}
.inner:nth-child(3) :nth-child(3) {
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
 <div id="outer">
   <div class="inner">
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
   </div>
   <div class="inner">
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
   </div>
   <div class="inner">
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: True but not scalable realistically

Comment: I agree, but if it's for a rubix cube it doesn't really need to scale. I would also suggest using class names instead of `nth-child` but I figured for the sake of answering the actual question I'd use them.

Comment: @Luke Thanks for your answer. Upvoted !! I will wait for more best solution. If not I will mark yours as complete.

Answer (score 0):

Just give each child an ID and use it to assign colours
  HTML IS:

```
<div id="outer">
                    <div>
                        <div id="child1">1</div>
                        <div id="child2">2</div>
                        <div id="child3">3</div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div id="child4">4</div>
                        <div id="child5">5</div>
                        <div id="child6">6</div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div id="child7">7</div>
                        <div id="child8">8</div>
                        <div id="child9">9</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS is:

```
#child1{
    background-color: red;
    color:red;
}

#child2{
    background-color: blue;
}

#child3{
    background-color: green;
}

#child4{
    background-color: pink;
}

#child5{
    background-color: yellow;
}

#child6{
    background-color: white;
}

#child7{
    background-color: black;
}

#child8{
    background-color: orange;
}

#child9{
    background-color: red;
}
```