# How to select every 1st and 3rd element with nth-child?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have divs all with class `.publication` and a width of 33%, so there are three divs per row:

```
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
```

I want to target every first and third element of each "row".

I thought this would do the trick, but it's not working.

```
.publication:nth-child(3n+1) {

}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css for more info on how nth-child works.

Answer (score 3):

You would need 2 selectors for first and third of every row:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

body :nth-child(3n+1), /* every first in row */
body :nth-child(3n) {  /* every third in row */
  background: blue;
}

.publication {
  width: 33.33333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not()` and have only one selector. The 1st and 3rd element is *not* a 2nd element

```css
.publication:not(:nth-child(3n+2)) {
  background: blue;
}

.publication {
  width: 33.33333%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need one rule to select the first element in each row and a separate one to select the last item in each row.

```css
.publication:nth-child(3n), .publication:nth-child(3n+1) {
}
```

```html
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found another possibility without :nth-child()

```
 .container { 
     display: flex; 
     flex-wrap: wrap; 
     justify-content: space-between; 
  }

 .publication { 
     max-width: 33%; 
     width: 100%; 
 }

 <div class="container">
     <div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
     <div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
     <div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
     <div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
     <div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div>
     <div class="publication">lorem ipsum</div> 
 </div>
```