# Set different font color based on array for all spans in a document?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Using JavaScript I would like to change the style of each `<span>` from an array of colors. Here is an example:

HTML:

```
        <span>H</span>
        <span>E</span>
        <span>L</span>
        <span>L</span>
        <span>O</span>
```

JS:

```
colors=['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'blue','green'];
[...document.querySelectorAll('span')].map( sp => {
         sp.style.color = colors[0];
         colors.shift();
});
```

Now my current thought is to spread my selection and use `map` so that I can iterate through each object. At the moment I am deleting elements in the colors as they are being used. I could also create an iterator to keep track of the colors so they do not get deleted. Assuming the number of objects and number of colors are the same I could also just step through with a for loop and set colors.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Map passes the index and the full array as the second and third parameters, respectively, to the function. So, something like: `.map((sp, idx) => { sp.style.color = colors[idx]; })` should work.

Comment: +1 @SumnerEvans, use forEach and not map function, and you do not need to use spread. `document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach((sp, i) => sp.style.color = colors[i]);`

Comment: alternativly this could also be done by using css only with the `:nth-child()` selector and using the `n-var`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `map()` returns a new *array* and you are not using it `forEach()` will be the better choice here.

You can parse to the arrow function inside your `forEach()` as by `map()` the **current element** and also as optional but here very useful the **index of the current element**.
This index you can use as indice for your colors array.

*Note: There is no need for `shift()` here so I removed it.*

Not asked here but good to know, when you have more *<span>* elements than colors you can use the remainder operator *%* to give the additional elements the right color. *(Begin from the start of the colors array again)*

```js
colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green'];
document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach((sp, ind) => {
  sp.style.color = colors[ind];
});
```

```html
<span>H</span>
<span>E</span>
<span>L</span>
<span>L</span>
<span>O</span>
```

Comment: There's no need to `.shift()` here. It will bork up the output because it's removing the item in the array, therefore making your index not work for the last 2.

Comment: @EJC Ty for the advice, yes I have already removed .shift()

Comment: @pilchard just trying to understand your comment here,  I understand the conversion of the array comes from map which is not required. where does the double querying of the DOM happen? is it from the use of spread?

Comment: The poster had been querying the DOM twice and not using the results of one but has since fixed the answer. I removed my earlier comment as it was addressed.

Answer (score 2):

As you noted in your question, `shift()` works, but destroys the color array at the same time. Also, [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array, which you aren't using and also requires that you convert your [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) to an array.

To solve all of these problems you can use the [`NodeList.prototype.forEach())`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method provided by the returned `NodeList` to iterate the list, and use the passed `index` to access the `colors` array.

(In your question the length of the `colors` array and the number of spans are the same, but if the number of `spans` increases any passed 5 won't be assigned colors. To solve this you can loop through the array by using the [remainder %](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) operator on the passed index `colors[i % colors.length]`)

```js
colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green'];
document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach((sp, i) => {
  sp.style.color = colors[i % colors.length];
});
```

```html
<span>H</span>
<span>E</span>
<span>L</span>
<span>L</span>
<span>O</span>
<span>W</span>
<span>O</span>
<span>R</span>
<span>L</span>
<span>D</span>
```

As **tacoshy** noted in the comments you can also achieve this with CSS using [functional notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#functional_notation) within an [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class rule. see: [Select every Nth element in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css) for more discussion.

```css
span:nth-child(5n+1) {
   color: red;
}
span:nth-child(5n+2) {
   color: orange;
}
span:nth-child(5n+3) {
   color: yellow;
}
span:nth-child(5n+4) {
   color: blue;
}
span:nth-child(5n+5) {
   color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>H</span>
  <span>E</span>
  <span>L</span>
  <span>L</span>
  <span>O</span> 
  <span>W</span>
  <span>O</span>
  <span>R</span>
  <span>L</span>
  <span>D</span>
</div>
```