# Selecting text using nth-of-type returns concatenated string

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML and I want to select the value "1933".

I tried `$('div.mydata dl:nth-of-type(1)').text()` but that returns "1933110 m243" where I'd expect "1933". What am I doing wrong?
I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css) already.

```js
console.log($('div.mydata dl:nth-of-type(1)').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydata">
  <div>
    <div class="left">
      Year: Lot size: Total: Cars: Motors:
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div>
        <dl>1933</dl>
      </div>
      <div>
        <dl>110 m<sup>2</sup></dl>
      </div>
      <div>
        N.A.
      </div>
      <div>
        <dl>4</dl>
      </div>
      <div>
        <dl>3</dl>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1: all your `<dl>` elements are the `:first-of-type` within their parents, and 2: that's not what a [`<dl>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) is used for; it's a description list, not a...whatever you think it is, there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector: `$('div.mydata dl:nth-of-type(1)').text()` is essentially selecting the first of every `<dl>` inside of `div.mydata`.

If you just want the contents of the first `<dl>` on the page use:

```
$($('div.mydata div dl').get(0)).text()
```