# Achieve nth-child to have nth-background image

Tags: css, loops, background

Hello is there a way to write css for let me say 100 elements with .class to have different background images?

So that first .class element will have background-img_1.svg, second .class element will have background-img_2.svg and so on...

I was thinking about workaround with ::before/::after and merge counter and image-url to content property but it seems I cannot merge two strings into content.

Comment: Not possible with CSS alone

Comment: Have a look at SASS or LESS.

Comment: This should be helpful: [helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css)

Comment: @AunZaidi "helpful link"  as link description is not helpful (accessibility rules). Beyond that, that link does not address the topic here. YOu have no arithmetic expression in this case. This is a case for a for-loop within CSS that will be provided by SASS and LESS, not by nth-child.

Answer (score 0):

As @Paulie_D said with CSS only isn't possible, you can use JavaScript.

```js
// gets all elements with the classname ".class"
const ELEMENTS = document.querySelectorAll('.class');

// counts how many elements exist with the classname ".class"
let numberOfElements = ELEMENTS.length;

// for-loop that iterates over the ELEMENTS Node-List 
for (let i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
  let element = ELEMENTS[i];
  let pathToImage = `background-img_${i + 1}.svg`;
  element.style.backgroundImage = pathToImage;
}
```

[W3Schools Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp)

Comment: Way too broad as an answer. Also, Paulie_D never stated that he has to use JS for it. As Gerard said, SASS and LESS would properly be more lightweight for it.

Comment: an answer is not a workaround to bypass account limitations. It also for obvious reasons is not allowed to do so. However, you are always free to edit your answers and write an answer compliment to the [answer] guidelines. Then also use a stacksnipept (`Ctrl+ M` or `<>` button) and show how your answer would solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

vanilla CSS can not do this an easy way. The easiest lightweight solution would be the usage of a pre-compiler such as SASS or LESS.

There you can make use of a `for-loop`:

```scss
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
  .class:nth-child(#{$i}) {
     background-image: url(background-img_#{$i}.svg);
  }
}
```

that would compile into normal CSS:

```css
.class:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url(background-img_1.svg);
}
.class:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(background-img_2.svg);
}

...

.class:nth-child(100) {
  background-image: url(Background-img_100.svg);
}
```